# jquery, manipulate the data in an ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In qwerty.php I'm able to load test.php with ajax, I also want to manipulate the data loaded in the success function but it doesn't seem to work.

In qwerty.php my code is

```
<div class="qwerty">qwerty</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'test.php', 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(data).find('.test1').click(function(){$(this).toggle();});
        $('.qwerty').before(data);

    }
});


});
</script>
```

and in test.php I have :

```
<div class="test1">test1</div>
<div class="test2">test2</div>
```

so my data is loaded correctly before the `div` "qwerty" but when I'm clicking on "test1" nothing happen.

Comment: find() looks into the descendants, and in your case you have 2 siblings. Just use filter() as they showed you in the answers.

Comment: @CristiPufu, that is not sufficient since the onclick is attached to an object different from the one inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work because you attach onclick to `$(data)` but insert `data` into the DOM. try this:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var el = $(data);
    el.find('.test1').addBack().filter('.test1').click(function(){$(this).toggle();});
    $('.qwerty').before(el);
}
```

I used `find(...).addBack().filter(...)` to find ALL elements matching your selector.
`find()` will find only child elements of test1 and test 1 having the class test one. `filter()` will only filter all the root elements, so if you have children elements, it won't search within those. thus the construct `find(...).addBack().filter(...)`

Answer (score 1):

use `filter()` since its a string that is returned

try this

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('.qwerty').before(data);
    $(data).filter('.test1').click(function(){$(this).toggle();});
}
```

**updated**

append the data first and use on delgated event...

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('.qwerty').before(data);
}
}); //ajax end


$('.qwerty').on('click' , '.test1' ,function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: wont work because you attach onclick to `$(data)` but insert `data`